# When does $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \phi (x) + \frac{a}{x} \int_{0}^{x} \phi (t) dt \Rightarrow \exists \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \phi (x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

The problem is stated as:

> When does the existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \phi (x) + \frac{a}{x} \int_{0}^{x} \phi (t) dt$ imply that $\exists \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \phi (x)$

**My attempt**

First of all, I thought that we suppose the opposite, that the limit doesn't exists for the latter part of the question. Therefore, it has to tend to $ \pm \infty$. Let's suppose $+ \infty$ WLOG.

Furthermore, rewriting the original expression, we get that:

$\frac{x\phi(x)+a\int_{0}^{x}\phi(t) dt}{x}$, which suddenly becomes a $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ case by our assumption. Applying L'Hospital, we get:

$\frac{\phi(x) + x\phi'(x)+a\phi(x)}{1}=(a+1)\phi(x)+x\phi'(x)$

In order for this limit to exists, $a = -1$, and $\phi'(x) = C/x$, for some real constant C. If we would've chosen $\phi'(x) = 1/x^\beta$ for $\beta < 1$, $\phi(x)$ would still stend to $\infty$ after integration, but $x\phi'(x)$ would tend to infinity,a nd the limit wouldn't exist. For $\beta > 1$, we would have that $\phi(x)$ wouldn't tend to $\infty$, breaking our original assumption.

So, to sum up, $a = -1$ and $\phi'(x) = C/x$ are necessary conditions in order for this statement to hold.

Please, if you have any ideas on what went wrong, feel free to share them. I'd be glad for any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that the limit doesn't exist does not imply that the sequence must diverge.

Comment: How is that? Since I let $\phi \rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, the integral itself must also diverge, and so both the numerator and denominator diverges. Or do you mean the $(a+1) \phi(x) ...$ part? Since that's also where I have some concerns regarding my solution.

Comment: Consider for example $\phi(x) = \sin(x)$. Then, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \phi(x)$ does not exist, but $\phi$ is bounded.

Comment: @user159517 Thats a good point. Thanks!